# Using NLS GERMAN shows wrong sorted output(load in chunks) in oracle

Tags: oracle, nls, nls-lang

[ORACLE DATABASE]
After setting,
alter session set nls_sort = GERMAN; 
alter session set nls_language = GERMAN;

When loading data in chunks and while using '>' to compare in order to get different sorted chunks shows incorrect data(gives duplicate entries).

Ex. for different chunks , 
using this in query... name > 'Account' or name > 'Project' or name > 'BB'
will give names 'aa' , 'bb' , 'cc' in every output.

Note, with nls_sort=BINARY and NLS_language=ENGLISH gives correct output.

Comment: What will happen if you uses `nls_sort = BINARY` instead of `nls_sort = GERMAN`?

Comment: "chunks"? What are they?

Comment: If there are lots of rows e.g. 5000 and we want to load in chunk(pagesize) , if chunksize is 1024 then it will give return first 1024 rows then next 1024 rows and so on..

Comment: Can you provide a fully reproducible test case?  I can think of some potential causes of this, depending on the characters, settings, and the functions used to compare.  For example, see some of [these examples](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28298/ch5lingsort.htm#i1006301).